# Use UART to transmit data Pic16f628A

Tags: pic, c, uart, bluetooth

I'm attempting to use the USART Module in the [PIC161F628A](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40044G.pdf) to communicate with a HC-06 bluetooth module. I've written my code in C in MPLAB X using XC8 compiler, however it doesn't seem to be working and can't figure out why?

Here is my code:

```
#include <xc.h>

#ifndef _XTAL_FREQ
   #define _XTAL_FREQ   4000000  // Hz
#endif

// Comm Setup.
#define BAUDRATE 9600

// Config words.
__CONFIG(FOSC_HS & WDTE_OFF & PWRTE_OFF & MCLRE_OFF & BOREN_ON & LVP_OFF & CPD_OFF & CP_OFF);
//__CONFIG(FOSC_INTOSCIO & WDTE_OFF & PWRTE_OFF & MCLRE_OFF & BOREN_ON & LVP_OFF & CPD_OFF & CP_OFF);

// Function that initializes UART.
void initUART(void) {

    // First calculate check if we have a high baudrate.
    unsigned int x;
    x = (_XTAL_FREQ - BAUDRATE*64)/(BAUDRATE*64);   // SPBRG for Low Baud Rate
    if(x>255) {
        x = (_XTAL_FREQ - BAUDRATE*16)/(BAUDRATE*16); // SPBRG for High Baud Rate
        BRGH = 1;                                     // Setting High Baud Rate
    } else {
        // Define pins.
        TRISB2 = 1;                                   // TX Pin
        TRISB1 = 1;                                   // RX Pin

        // Define UART setup.
        SPBRG = x;                                    // Writing SPBRG Register
        SYNC = 0;                                     // Setting Asynchronous Mode, ie UART
        SPEN = 1;                                     // Enables Serial Port
        CREN = 1;                                     // Enables Continuous Reception
        TXIE  = 0;                                    // Disable tx interrupts
        //RCIE  = 1;                                    // Enable rx interrupts
        RCIE = 0;
        TX9   = 0;                                    // 8-bit transmission
        RX9   = 0;                                    // 8-bit reception
        TXEN  = 0;                                    // Reset transmitter
        TXEN = 1;                                     // Enables Transmission
    }
}

// Function that sends characters through serial port.
void sendData(char data) {
   while(!TRMT);  // wait for previous transmission to finish
   TXREG = data;
}

// Function that sends strings through serial port.
void sendString(char* text) {
    int i;
    for(i=0;text[i]!='\0';i++)
        sendData(text[i]);
}

char UART_TX_Empty() {
  return TRMT;
}

// Main function.
void main(void) {

    TRISB = 0; // PORTB as Output.
    nRBPU = 0;    // Enables PORTB Internal Pull Up Resistors
    // Initialize UART.
    initUART();
    while(1) {

        // Send string through UART.
        sendString("Hello!");
        __delay_ms(300);
    }
}
```

I've verified that the bluetooth module is working correctly by connecting it to my laptop and using it to send and receive strings to my phone. I've also verified that the microcontroller is working correctly by writing a simple 'Hello World' program of a LED blinking.

I've been trying to get this working for a couple of days now and I'm pretty frustrated at this point, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: can you spot anything wrong with my code? It's not working and I'm trying to figure out why?

Comment: TRISB2 = 1; // TX Pin
This should be 0 as it is an output can you attach datasheet for this pic?

Comment: Tried that, still not working for some reason, this is the link of the datasheet: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40044G.pdf

Comment: Not working in what way?

Comment: When I load the code to the microcontroller and power it up with everything connected. I pair the my phone to the bluetooth module and I should see in the terminal "Hello!" as output continuously, however nothing comes up in the terminal

Comment: @patrickdamery Also make sure all analog features of the pin are disabled.  That's done by setting the ANSELx bits to zero.  You do need to look at the physical signals coming out and to the micro.

Comment: change FOSC_HS to XT as it is 4 MHZ ((see data sheet))

Comment: @SunnyBoyNY I don't think that's necessary in this case, because both pins RB1 and RB2 cannot be analog inputs or outputs, unless I'm misunderstanding the datasheet?

Comment: Made the change and still no luck I'm afraid

Comment: get a real UART not bluetooth and try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I know this is an old question but I'll give an answer anyway)

There is something wrong in your code structure: dont use an else clause on line 23.

Since x is obviously greater than 255 (4000000/9600 > 255) the pin and USART initialization is never performed.

Debugging by stepping through your code would reveal that.

Comment: Yeah that's right, I actually already fixed this but I had forgotten to update this. The other problem was that I couldn't achieve the baud rate I needed with the frequency of my oscillator (4MHz), so I had to set the BRGH  bit and then I had to set the SPBRG value to 25 if I remember correctly, it's all in the manual anyway, I'll accept your answer as it was the closest to solving the problem!

Answer (score 1):

1. Check your wiring
2. Check the BT connection on its own: connect RX and TX together without the PIC
3. Check the PIC connection on its own: connect RX and TX together without the BT module

You should receive your transmitted data on the same channel.

Comment: I've verified the wiring and that's not it, also checked the BT connection by connecting it to my laptop using a USB to CP2102 TTL converter and communication worked perfectly. I'll check the PIC on its own but I highly doubt that is the problem, I've got a dozen of them and code doesn't seem to work with any of them.